# Samba 4 Domain controller: authentication from windows client stopped working

Tags: samba, active-directory, windows-domain, windows-authentication

I've set up a samba 4 domain controller, we have four Windows 7/8 clients in the domain. This setup worked for the past 6 months.

Recently, I've not been able to log in with my credentials from two of these machines. The strange thing is: I tried to remove one of these machines from the domain and re-joined it using my credentials. But then again, login with the very same credentials didn't work.

I also used a [userauth](https://userauth.codeplex.com/) tool from codeplex to check the authentication against Active Directory, it worked from one machine while it didn't from the other.

I suspect that somehow the "trust" between the client and the domain controller is broken (the only active change I can remember was to assign a fixed IP address to the client, sometimes we are also experiencing DNS problems), but I'm far from sure about this.

Not being an expert at all in these matters, I would highly appreciate any hints what could possibly go wrong and/or what to try/check in order to diagnose/solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After a few sleepless hours, I finally found the error: The **system time** on the two machines was off more than 5 minutes from the server's time. This caused the kerberos authentication system to fail.

I'm still not sure, why these machines do not get the automatic time update (the samba 4 server should be acting as NTP server after all), but the primary issue is solved.